# Как перенаправить порты для определенного IP

Tags: linux, iptables

имея iptables я хочу чтоб для определенного IP подключаясь на порт X, он на самом деле подключался к порту Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключения с `IP` `192.0.2.0` по протоколу `tcp` на порт `80` переправить на порт `8080` в простом варианте можно как-то так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 192.0.2.0 --dport 80 \
         -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Если узел не является оконечным и есть транзитный трафик то набор/структура правил может несколько усложняться в зависимости от потребностей...